# screen rotation by unlocking screen

Tags: android, rotation, screen

I have a problem.
I wrote an app that can only be displayed vertically. The problem is that my app, if it appears by the autostart, before the autostart, the barrier completely ignored and can rotated there.

The problem only occurs with Android 7 and higher.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

In android `Manifest` file, to your `activity` `Tag`, add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`.

Comment: sorry the lock is indeed on the one hand from the "Tag" and the "setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)"